# Applying a function iteratively to its own results in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
dat <- structure(list(year = c(2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017), CD = c(246.74, 
271.25, 295.21, 307.46, 405.82, 391.65, 439.1, 538.39, 549.27, 
559.94, 510.51, 516.14, 480.25, 472.18, 460.56), Growth = c(1.17, 
0.94, 1.05, 0.95, 1, 1.04, 1.09, 1.08, 1, 1.08, 0.97, 0.99, 1.06, 
0.99, 0.99)), .Names = c("year", "CD", "Growth"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

which looks like

```
   year     CD    Growth
16 2003  246.74   1.17
17 2004  271.25   0.94
18 2005  295.21   1.05
19 2006  307.46   0.95
20 2007  405.82   1.00
21 2008  391.65   1.04
22 2009  439.10   1.09
23 2010  538.39   1.08
24 2011  549.27   1.00
25 2012  559.94   1.08
26 2013  510.51   0.97
27 2014  516.14   0.99
28 2015  480.25   1.06
29 2016  472.18   0.99
30 2017  460.56   0.99
```

What I need to do is create a new column, call is `KD`, which takes the following value:

1. For the year 2007, `CD`
2. For all years after 2007, `KD of the year before * Growth of the current year`
3. For all years before 2007, `KD of the following year / Growth of the current year`

In other words, 2007 serves as a reference year, and `KD[year == 2007]` should be **405.82**, `KD[year == 2008]` should be **422.05** (`405.82 * 1.04`) and `KD[year == 2009]` should be **460.04** (`422.05 * 1.09`)

Meanwhile, `KD[year == 2006]` should be **427.18** (`405.82 / 0.95`) and `KD[year == 2005]` is **406.84** (`427.18 / 1.05`)

Is there a simple way to do this in R without using cumbersome for-loops?

Comment: You could do it without for loops with the help of cumprod, ifelse, and some math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dat%>%mutate(l=CD[year==2007])%>%
  group_by(s=cumsum(year==2007))%>%
  mutate(KD=ifelse(s==0,l/rev(cumprod(rev(Growth))),l*cumprod(Growth)),l=NULL)%>%
  data.frame()


   year     CD Growth s       KD
1  2003 246.74   1.17 0 369.9192
2  2004 271.25   0.94 0 432.8054
3  2005 295.21   1.05 0 406.8371
4  2006 307.46   0.95 0 427.1789
5  2007 405.82   1.00 1 405.8200
6  2008 391.65   1.04 1 422.0528
7  2009 439.10   1.09 1 460.0376
8  2010 538.39   1.08 1 496.8406
9  2011 549.27   1.00 1 496.8406
10 2012 559.94   1.08 1 536.5878
11 2013 510.51   0.97 1 520.4902
12 2014 516.14   0.99 1 515.2853
13 2015 480.25   1.06 1 546.2024
14 2016 472.18   0.99 1 540.7404
15 2017 460.56   0.99 1 535.3330
```

Comment: @user what do you mean by your comment? First any base year will have a growth of 1, that is why it is the base year, second, I do not understand what assumption you are talking about

Comment: @Onyambu is correct.  Since 2007 is the base year, its growth is 1 by definition. KD for the year 2007 should be the same as CD, so multiplying it by 1 is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

We can do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(KD_ref = CD[year == 2007],
         Growth_cumdiv = c(rev(cumprod(rev(1/Growth[year < 2007]))), 
                           rep(NA, sum(year >= 2007))),
         Growth_cumprod = c(rep(NA, sum(year <= 2007)), 
                            cumprod(Growth[year > 2007])),
         KD = case_when(
    year < 2007 ~ KD_ref*Growth_cumdiv
    year == 2007 ~ KD_ref,
    year > 2007 ~ KD_ref*Growth_cumprod,
  ))
```

**Result:**

```
   year     CD Growth KD_ref Growth_cumdiv Growth_cumprod       KD
1  2003 246.74   1.17 405.82     0.9115351             NA 369.9192
2  2004 271.25   0.94 405.82     1.0664960             NA 432.8054
3  2005 295.21   1.05 405.82     1.0025063             NA 406.8371
4  2006 307.46   0.95 405.82     1.0526316             NA 427.1789
5  2007 405.82   1.00 405.82            NA             NA 405.8200
6  2008 391.65   1.04 405.82            NA       1.040000 422.0528
7  2009 439.10   1.09 405.82            NA       1.133600 460.0376
8  2010 538.39   1.08 405.82            NA       1.224288 496.8406
9  2011 549.27   1.00 405.82            NA       1.224288 496.8406
10 2012 559.94   1.08 405.82            NA       1.322231 536.5878
11 2013 510.51   0.97 405.82            NA       1.282564 520.4902
12 2014 516.14   0.99 405.82            NA       1.269738 515.2853
13 2015 480.25   1.06 405.82            NA       1.345923 546.2024
14 2016 472.18   0.99 405.82            NA       1.332464 540.7404
15 2017 460.56   0.99 405.82            NA       1.319139 535.3330
```

One can also make it a function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

KD_calc <- function(DF, ref_year, KD_colname){
  KD_colname_quo = quo_name(enquo(KD_colname))
  DF %>%
    mutate(KD_ref = CD[year == ref_year],
           Growth_cumdiv = c(rev(cumprod(rev(1/Growth[year < ref_year]))), 
                             rep(NA, sum(year >= ref_year))),
           Growth_cumprod = c(rep(NA, sum(year <= ref_year)), 
                              cumprod(Growth[year > ref_year])),
           UQ(KD_colname_quo) := case_when(
             year < ref_year ~ KD_ref*Growth_cumdiv,
             year == ref_year ~ KD_ref,
             year > ref_year ~ KD_ref*Growth_cumprod,
           )) %>%
    select(-KD_ref, -Growth_cumdiv, -Growth_cumprod)
}
```

**Result:**

```
> KD_calc(df, 2007, KD)
   year     CD Growth       KD
1  2003 246.74   1.17 369.9192
2  2004 271.25   0.94 432.8054
3  2005 295.21   1.05 406.8371
4  2006 307.46   0.95 427.1789
5  2007 405.82   1.00 405.8200
6  2008 391.65   1.04 422.0528
7  2009 439.10   1.09 460.0376
8  2010 538.39   1.08 496.8406
9  2011 549.27   1.00 496.8406
10 2012 559.94   1.08 536.5878
11 2013 510.51   0.97 520.4902
12 2014 516.14   0.99 515.2853
13 2015 480.25   1.06 546.2024
14 2016 472.18   0.99 540.7404
15 2017 460.56   0.99 535.3330
```